# .push in JavaScript won't push data back to the array, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var text = "blah blah Josh bbla Josh Josh";

var myName = "Josh";
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++);{
    if (text[i] === myName[0]) {
        for (var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);    
        }
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Why won't this code send the data into the array? It feels like I have tried everything, and according to online forums this is the correct synthax. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What does your `console.log(hits)` show you?

Comment: Look at the first `for(...);{...}` . That `;` should not be there.

Comment: Also, try with `var text = "blah blah Joker blah blah"` after you remove the extra `;` in the code as suggested, and see where that gets you

Comment: @Christos Paisios — You changed the behavior of the code when you edited the post. Please, don't do that again.

Comment: @DCoder Thank you! Did not see that extra semi-colon!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the semicolon before the opening curly bracket. That semicolon now forms the body of the for loop, which does nothing as a result.

```
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++);{
```

Answer (score 0):

If "pushing data" is what you are concerned about you will only have to remove the semicolon before that curly brace at the end of line 6 which reads:

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++);{
```

which should make that chunk of for loop execute just right. It should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === myName[0]) {
        for (var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you come up with nearly the exact answer that [Daniël Knippers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2858155/daniel-knippers) gave about 17min before you, but you should always mark code as code.

Comment: @ztirom precisely because we both talk of the right solution.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to loop twice;
Just split the string and loop once, like this:

```
var text = "blah blah Josh bbla Josh Josh";
var myName = "Josh";
var hits = [];

text = text.split(" ")
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] === myName){
    hits.push(text[i]);    
}
}
if(hits.length === 0) {
  console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else{
  console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If you want to know if a string contains another substring, better use

```
if("blah blah Josh bbla Josh Josh".indexOf("Josh") < 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");}
else {
    // Whatever
}
```

Or, in case you really want to get `['J','o','s','h','J','o',...]`, you can use

```
"blah blah Josh bbla Josh Josh".match(/Josh/g).join('').split('')
```

Answer (score -2):

You just happen to be getting a value for string.length which tells you how many characters.  You probably aren't actually trying to loop through the string.  Instead, it seems like you want to split the string into an array of names - breaking at a space:

```
var names = text.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++);{
```